# Unable to see logs after upgrading to ActiveMQ 5.18.2

Tags: activemq-classic, log4j2

We are trying to dockerize the ActiveMQ service. We are using the [public ActiveMQ repo](https://github.com/apache/activemq) as the base code. We are bringing the ActiveMQ service inside the container using the wrapper. Service is working fine. We are able to connect to broker and admin web console but we are not able to see any logs. This is happening after upgrading from ActiveMQ 5.17.3 to 5.18.2. I am seeing this error or warning in wrapper logs - `SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder"`. Detailed logs of wrapper are as below.

```
jvm 1    |   Heap sizes: current=192512k  free=187553k  max=1048576k
jvm 1    |     JVM args: --add-reads=java.xml=java.logging --add-opens=java.base/java.security=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.naming/javax.naming.spi=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.jar=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.xml.dom/org.w3c.dom.html=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.naming.rmi/com.sun.jndi.url.rmi=ALL-UNNAMED -Dactivemq.home=../.. -Dactivemq.base=../.. -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=password -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=password -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=../../conf/broker.ks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=../../conf/broker.ts -Dorg.apache.activemq.UseDedicatedTaskRunner=true -Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties -Dactivemq.conf=../../conf -Dactivemq.data=../../data -Djava.security.auth.login.config=../../conf/login.config -XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError -Dauth.mode=default -Xmx1024m -Djava.library.path=../../bin/linux-x86-64/ -Dwrapper.key=WWR9_RuW0MMrJoRl -Dwrapper.port=32000 -Dwrapper.jvm.port.min=31000 -Dwrapper.jvm.port.max=31999 -Dwrapper.debug=TRUE -Dwrapper.pid=44 -Dwrapper.version=3.2.3 -Dwrapper.native_library=wrapper -Dwrapper.cpu.timeout=10 -Dwrapper.jvmid=1
jvm 1    | Extensions classpath:
jvm 1    |   [../../lib,../../lib/camel,../../lib/optional,../../lib/web,../../lib/extra]
jvm 1    | ACTIVEMQ_HOME: ../..
jvm 1    | ACTIVEMQ_BASE: ../..
jvm 1    | ACTIVEMQ_CONF: ../../conf
jvm 1    | ACTIVEMQ_DATA: ../../data
jvm 1    | SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
jvm 1    | SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
jvm 1    | SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
jvm 1    | Loading message broker from: xbean:activemq.xml
jvm 1    | Send a packet START_PENDING : 5000
wrapperp | read a packet START_PENDING : 5000
wrapper  | JVM signalled a start pending with waitHint of 5000 millis.
```

I don't see the above class load error in ActiveMQ 5.17.3. Could someone please help here?

We should be able to see ActiveMQ logs in `activemq.log`.

Below is the dockerfile .

```
FROM <base_image_jdk11_ol8>

ENV AMQ_VERSION=5.17.3
ENV TAR_BALL apache-activemq-$AMQ_VERSION

WORKDIR /container

RUN curl "<base_url>/custom/apache-activemq-$AMQ_VERSION-bin.tar.gz" -o $TAR_BALL-bin.tar.gz
#COPY apache-activemq-${AMQ_VERSION}-bin.tar.gz /container

RUN tar -xvz -f /container/apache-activemq-${AMQ_VERSION}-bin.tar.gz
RUN rm -rf /container/apache-activemq-${AMQ_VERSION}-bin.tar.gz
RUN mv /container/apache-activemq-${AMQ_VERSION} /container/activemq
WORKDIR /container/activemq

RUN groupadd -g 498 activemq
RUN useradd -u 498 -g 498 activemq
ENV ACTIVEMQ_USER=activemq

RUN mkdir -p /etc/activemq
RUN mkdir -p /var/log/activemq
RUN mkdir -p /run/activemq/jetty/api
RUN mkdir -p /run/activemq/jetty/fileserver
RUN mkdir -p /run/activemq/jetty/admin

COPY ./snapshots/amq-jaas-vault-*.jar ./lib
COPY ./snapshots/jetty-jaas-*.jar ./lib/web

COPY ./etc/activemq/activemq.xml ./conf
COPY ./etc/activemq/activemq-broker-vault.xml ./conf
COPY ./etc/activemq/activemq-broker-default.xml ./conf
COPY ./etc/activemq/jetty.xml ./conf
COPY ./etc/activemq/jetty-default.xml ./conf
COPY ./etc/activemq/jetty-vault.xml ./conf
COPY ./etc/activemq/amq-vault.properties ./conf
COPY ./etc/activemq/log4j2.properties ./conf
COPY ./etc/activemq/login.config ./conf

COPY ./usr/share/activemq/bin/linux-x86-64/activemq ./bin/linux-x86-64
COPY ./usr/share/activemq/bin/linux-x86-64/wrapper.conf ./bin/linux-x86-64
COPY ./usr/share/activemq/bin/jolokia-credentials /usr/bin
COPY ./usr/share/activemq/bin/replay-activemq-dlq /usr/bin
COPY ./usr/share/activemq/webapps/admin/WEB-INF/webconsole-embedded-vault.xml ./webapps/admin/WEB-INF//webconsole-embedded-vault.xml
COPY ./usr/share/activemq/webapps/admin/WEB-INF/webconsole-embedded-default.xml ./webapps/admin/WEB-INF/webconsole-embedded-default.xml
COPY ./usr/share/activemq/webapps/admin/WEB-INF/webconsole-embedded.xml ./webapps/admin/WEB-INF/webconsole-embedded.xml
COPY ./usr/share/activemq/webapps/admin/WEB-INF/web.xml ./webapps/admin/WEB-INF

RUN chown -R activemq:activemq /container/activemq
RUN chown -R activemq:activemq /run/activemq
RUN chown -R activemq:activemq /var/log/activemq

EXPOSE 8161
EXPOSE 61616

ENTRYPOINT ["./bin/linux-x86-64/activemq", "console"]
```

We have some custom configuration changes, otherwise, we are not changing any library of activemq

Comment: Looks like your container is using SLF4J 1.x, while ActiveMQ 5.18.x expects SLF4J 2.x. Can you add you `Dockerfile` to your question?

Comment: Thanks for the response @PiotrP.Karwasz . I have added the dockerfile to the question. Same dockerfile works if I change the activemq version to 5.17.3.